# How to associate an object with ToolStripMenuItem VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Apple
    Private d_isplayName As String
    Public Property DisplayName() As String
        Get
            Return d_isplayName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            d_isplayName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private u_niqueVal As String
    Public Property uniqueVal() As String
        Get
            Return u_niqueVal
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            u_niqueVal = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim RedApple As New Apple With {.DisplayName = "redapple", .uniqueVal = "Uval"}
    tsiAddFruit.DropDownItems.Add("Some Text", Nothing, AddressOf fruit_Click)' Work fine
    tsiAddFruit.DropDownItems.Add(RedApple, Nothing, AddressOf fruit_Click)' does not work
End Sub

Private Sub fruit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim MenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    MessageBox.Show(MenuItem.Text)
End Sub
```

How can I pass an object in ToolStripMenuItem without using the `.Tag` property(no third-party tool too)? I want to use `Apple.DisplayName` and the display value and `Apple.UniqueVal` as the value type.

Comment: You can inherit `ToolStripMenuItem` and add your own members to provide the functionality you want, then use your class instead of the standard option. You're using an OO language so use OO principles. Inheritance is one of the absolute fundamentals of OOP.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I Created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65732924/5326036) because I tried what you suggested and I ran into some issues, am I using the inheritance the right way? or have you got any examples?

Comment: `tsiAddFruit.DropDownItems.Add(RedApple, Nothing, AddressOf fruit_Click)` I don't see an overload of the .Add method that takes (Object, Image, Event). (String, Image, Event) is the closest. RedApple is not a String.